# get files list of particular mimetype in specified directory

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm successfully getting files in specified directory using request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="1bmCj4FYUVVuxq6sUnGFKrizAjwtbq7XD"+in+parents
```

(but it includes files of all mimetypes).

Also I'm successfully getting files of specified mimetype using request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27
```

(but it includes files of all my directories).

Now how do I get files of particular mimetype in specified directory? I tried something like

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="1bmCj4FYUVVuxq6sUnGFKrizAjwtbq7XD"+in+parents&mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27
```

or

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27&"1bmCj4FYUVVuxq6sUnGFKrizAjwtbq7XD"+in+parents
```

though it considers only the first parameter, but not both parameters. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For initial question: (Solved)

- You want to retrieve the files with the specific mimeType in a specific folder.

If my understanding is correct, for query, how about modifying as follows? Please use `and` for your case.

```
'1bmCj4FYUVVuxq6sUnGFKrizAjwtbq7XD' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
```

So can you try to use as following endpoint?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%271bmCj4FYUVVuxq6sUnGFKrizAjwtbq7XD%27%20in%20parents%20and%20mimeType%3d%27application%2fvnd%2egoogle%2dapps%2espreadsheet%27
```

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)

If I misunderstand your issue, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### For 2nd question: (Solved)

For example, if you want to retrieve files from 2 folders, please use the following query. In this case, files from folder ID 1 and folder ID 2 are retrieved.

```
'### folder ID 1 ###' in parents or '### folder ID 2 ###' in parents
```

### For 3rd question: (Solved)

When you want to retrieve files with the mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` in several folders, please try to use the following query.

```
('1bmCj4FYUVVuxq6sUnGFKrizAjwtbq7XD' in parents or '1QR_Thw-5xZmGVZAkUeeDXQ4KhA55t2Pm' in parents) and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
```

### For 4th question: (Solved)

Unfortunately, the file list cannot be directly retrieved by the folder name using the query. Because the same folder names can be existing in Google Drive. So it is required to use the following flow.

1. Convert the folder name to folder ID using the following query. If several folders are included in the result, please retrieve one of them.

   - `name='### folder name ###' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false`
2. Retrieve file list using the converted folder ID. You can use the query from 1st to 3rd answer.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike! It worked for me with **and** keyword. Just in case, here is my full url (not all symbols need to be urlencoded)
`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="1bmCj4FYUVVuxq6sUnGFKrizAjwtbq7XD"+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27`

Comment: Is there any way to set multiple folders btw?

Comment: @marco I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. For your new question, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: No problem, I guess the need to encode particular symbols depends on environment.

Comment: Now regarding `or` keyword. Right now it does not work as it should, when I try to combine `or` with `and` keywords. For example, my url `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="1bmCj4FYUVVuxq6sUnGFKrizAjwtbq7XD"+in+parents+or+"1QR_Thw-5xZmGVZAkUeeDXQ4KhA55t2Pm"+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27` returns spreadsheets from needed two directories, but it also returns **doc** that I don't want. So.. how do I set conditions like `((folder1 or folder2) and mimetype=something)` ? Brackets are important here. Please advise.

Comment: Is there any way to request folder by its real name in gdrive UI, not by its folder ID 
btw ?

Comment: @marco Can I ask you about your situation? 1. At first, can I ask you whether my answer for your 2nd question worked? 2. I added an answer for your 3rd question. Could you please confirm it? 3. About your 4th question, I cannot understand about what you want to do. Can you explain the detail information? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: 1. It worked for multiple folders. 2. It worked for multiple folders and mimetype. 3. I mean that folder in GDrive UI (website) has its user-defined name. My question is, is it possible to request list of files by real user-defined name in user's account? Another option is getting folder ID by its user-defined name in UI. Is it possible at all?

Comment: @marco I could understand my 2nd and 3rd answer resolved your issues. About your 4th question, you want to retrieve files in a folder using the folder name instead of the folder ID. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You are right about your 2nd and 3rd answer. Also you are right, I want to retrieve files in folder(s) using the folder(s) name(s) instead of the folder(s) ID(s). I am writing application for users that are not so advanced in computers, thus folder ID might be confusing and/or not so convenient. Please advise is it possible at all.

Comment: @marco I could understand about your 4th question. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Confirmed regarding my 4th question, works fine, thanks.

Comment: @marco Thank you for your response.

Comment: How do I get list of spreadsheets from folder that has special (umlaut) symbol ä, ö, ü in folder's name? How about cyrillic?

Comment: @marco I cannot understand about your situation. So can you post it as new question? If you can do, please include the detail information. By this, it will help users think of your issue.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. It works indeed. The only thing was that my folder name contained space and I should change it to plus (+) symbol. Thanks again.

Comment: @marco Thank you for replying. I'm glad you issue was resolved.